# Sqlite date field error for transactions

Tags: python, database, sqlite

trying to build two databases, one for houses, and another for the dates and prices that they were sold for in the last 16 years

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('houses_in_london.db')
database = conn.cursor()
database.execute('CREATE TABLE houses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, address TEXT,'
                 ' area TEXT NOT NULL, postcode TEXT, bedrooms TEXT)')
database.execute('CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_id INTEGER, house_id INTEGER, '
                 'FOREIGN KEY(house_id) REFERENCES houses(id), date TEXT, sale_price INTEGER )')
database.commit()
database.close()
```

if you guys notice, I am trying to put a date field in the transactions table to mark each sale and have it as a text field, but It returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saminahbab/Documents/House_Prices/final_spider.py", line 14, in <module>
    database.execute('CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_id INTEGER, house_id INTEGER, '
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DATE": syntax error
```

which does not make sense to me as I am just trying to create a text date field, which should pass, and I can do analysis with pandas which can read in that field and turn it into date objects.
anyone can help me make the date field?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can mix foreign key and column definitions. I would simply move the foreign key definition to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more concise syntax does the needeful

```
database.execute(
   'CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_id INTEGER, house_id INTEGER '
   'REFERENCES houses(id), date TEXT, sale_price INTEGER )')
```

Alternatively, you need to move the constraints to the end of the create statement

```
database.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_id INTEGER, house_id INTEGER, '
    'date TEXT, sale_price INTEGER,
    'FOREIGN KEY(house_id) REFERENCES houses(id) )')
```

Comment: hey man, thats sorted it out thank you, but I dont understand why, the main difference here is that foreign key is taken out, but even with it surely it still makes sense?

Comment: thank you e4c5, is your username a succession of chess moves?

Comment: Yes fellow chess player, I have named my account after the Sicilian Defence

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> CREATE TABLE includes one or more column definitions, optionally followed by a list of table constraints.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

This is syntactiaclly a table constraint and MUST go after all column definitions:

```
FOREIGN KEY(house_id) REFERENCES houses(id)
```

This is a column definition and can be between other column definitions:

```
house_id INTEGER REFERENCES houses(id)
```